# How to check if future method has executed

Tags: apex, future, asynchronous

in my apex code I need to do some calculation only when future method has executed
I tried below code to check if future method has executed:

```
public static void anotherMethod() {
while('Completed' != checkFutureMethod()) {
            checkFutureMethod();
         }

// need to do something here only when future method has executed
}

 private static string checkFutureMethod() {
        string asyncApexStatus;
        for(AsyncApexJob asyncApex : [select Status From AsyncApexJob where ApexClass.Name = 'classname']) {
                                 asyncApexStatus = asyncApex.Status; 
                              }
        return asyncApexStatus;

    }
```

but still the above doesn't wait future method to finish, please suggest.

Comment: did u try this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40679/is-there-any-way-of-confirming-that-an-future-method-has-been-called-queued-in

Comment: Thank you for your response but the link provided is about future method in test class

Answer (score 7):

First, asynchronous methods will **never** even start until the previous transaction commits, so any wait loop would need to be asynchronous itself. Secondly, if you need the status of an asynchronous call, use [Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) instead. Unlike future methods, Queueable methods provide a JobId, which you can query against to see if the unit has executed, and if it did so successfully.

```
MyQueueable someQueueable = new MyQueueable();
Id jobId = System.enqueueJob(someQueueable);

// ... some time later ... //
AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :jobId];
```

Remember, you must allow the current transaction to complete before the asynchronous code can run, so you'll need a mechanism to wait, such as using a Visualforce page with apex:actionPoller.

Presumably, your code will find the first future method ever to be called by that class, thus will immediately return as completed. There's no way to determine which future method is which with 100% accuracy, which is one reason why Queueable was invented.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, so should I keep running SOQL on asyncApex until I get completed status the way I was doing with the future in question?

Comment: @gs650x You'll likely hit governor limits if you try this. You'll need to design a way to check back later without the loop. I'd need to know more about what the context for what you're trying to do (e.g. Visualforce, trigger, etc) to provide an appropriate alternative solution.

Comment: it is LWC and on a click of button it updates on so many objects and to avoid governor limit it is future method.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox i tried to convert content version blob data to base64Encoded in lwc javascript side, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416114/need-to-do-base64encode-conversion-in-client-side-to-avoid-cpu-heap-size-governo , but facing issue can you please help